# schemas and triggers in postgres

Tags: postgresql

here is my script:

```
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS {accountId};
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {accountId}.{tableCommandsName}
(
    id              int         GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    ts              timestamp   WITHOUT TIME ZONE NOT NULL,
    command         varchar     NOT NULL,
    ts_executed     timestamp   WITHOUT TIME ZONE,
    output          varchar
);

CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS idx_commands ON {accountId}.{tableCommandsName} (ts_executed) WHERE ts_executed IS NULL;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW {accountId}.pending_commands AS
    SELECT id, ts, command from {accountId}.{tableCommandsName} WHERE ts_executed IS NULL ORDER BY ts ASC;

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION {accountId}.on_commands_change ()
    RETURNS trigger
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
AS $BODY$
    DECLARE
      notification JSON;
    BEGIN
        notification = json_build_object(
            'table',TG_TABLE_NAME,
            'data', row_to_json(NEW));

        PERFORM pg_notify('datachange', notification::TEXT);
        RETURN NEW;
    END
$BODY$;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER {triggerName}
    AFTER INSERT ON {accountId}.{tableCommandsName}
    FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE {accountId}.on_commands_change();
```

my focus is the line:

> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER {triggerName}

where

> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER {accountId}.{triggerName}

will not work, but

> CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "{accountId}.{triggerName}"

will work, and I don't understand why.

everything else has the schema name in front, but the trigger doesn't want it.

and if I don't put it, it's still created in the right schema. Is it because it's during the same execution as the create schema instruction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtrigger.html)

> The name cannot be schema-qualified — the trigger inherits the schema of its table

Comment: so the trigger name inherits the schema of the table it is monitoring?